# Scala Specs2 (version 3.x) - How create and work with Notifier?

Tags: scala, specs2

How to correctly work with Scala Specs2 [Notifier](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.3.12/index.html#org.specs2.reporter.Notifier)?

Haven't found any example to demonstrate some use cases of the Notifier trait.

**Edit:**

When using Notifier as follows, it works flawlessly:

```
class TestSpec extends TestUtils {

  "Arithmetic" should {
    "add two numbers" in {
      1 + 1 mustEqual 2
    }

    "add three numbers" in {
      1 + 1 + 1 mustEqual 3
    }
  }
}
class TestNotifier extends ConsoleNotifier

trait TestUtils extends Specification {
  args.report(notifier = "com.stuff.TestNotifier")
}
```

But, when i'm trying to add some new context creation for each test:

```
class TestSpec extends TestUtils {

  trait Context {
    val justNum = 4
  }

  "Arithmetic" should {
    "add two numbers" in new Context {
      1 + 1 mustEqual 2
    }

    "add three numbers" in new Context {
      1 + 1 + 1 mustEqual 3
    }
  }
}
```

errors appear:

> Error:(12, 23) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[TestSpec.this.Context]
>       "add two numbers" in new Context {

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Notifier. You get this message because `Context` needs to extend `org.specs2.specification.Scope` to be able to be used as an Example body.

Comment: Also at the moment I'm not using the specification arguments to determine how to run it. So the notifier argument has to be passed on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Eric, now it works. Will remember it for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.0.x documentation for `Notifier` is [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0.1/org.specs2.guide.CustomOutput.html#notifier) (and the corresponding API is [there](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-3.0.1/index.html#org.specs2.reporter.Notifier)).

Basically you need to define a class implementing the `Notifier` trait and then called it with the `notifier` argument:

```
sbt> testOnly *BinarySpec* -- notifier org.acme.reporting.FtpNotifier
```

You can have a look at the [`ConsoleNotifier`](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/specs2/reporter/Notifier.scala#L29) for a simple example of an implementation.

Comment: Thanks Eric, i succeeded to do basic Notifier, but, it doesn't work in more specific case that i have. Edited the question, would be thankful for your further assistance.